# JOIN query, ON same key

Tags: sql, select, join

I have some tables. Most important ones in this JOIN query are:

`table 'changes' columns:

|----|------------|----------|------------|-----|----------------|

| id | teacher_id | class_id | subject_id | day | new_teacher_id |

|----|------------|----------|------------|-----|----------------|

|----|--sample input:--------|------------|-----|----------------|

|---1|-----------1|---------1|-----------1|2002-02-02|----------2|`

`table 'teachers' columns:

|----|---------|

| id | teacher |

|----|---------|

|sample input:-|

|---1|mr. Johnson|

|---2|mr. John-|

|--------------|`

The query below works fine:

`SELECT c.day, t.teacher, cl.class, s.subjectname

FROM changes AS c

LEFT JOIN teachers AS t ON c.teacher_id = t.id

JOIN classes AS cl ON c.class_id = cl.id

JOIN subjects AS s ON c.subject_id = s.id`

But I also want to make something like:

`LEFT JOIN teachers AS t ON c.teacher_id = t.id AND c.new_teacher_id = t.id`

That **does not** work.

Any ideas how to JOIN two columns from the same table with one key column from another?

Comment: Do you want to join `teachers` one more time, or it's a replacement of your old join condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join a table multiple times by giving it separate aliases:

```
SELECT t2a.name AS one_name, t2b.name AS two_name, ...
FROM table1 AS t1 JOIN table2 AS t2a (ON t2a.id = t1.one_id)
                  JOIN table2 AS t2b (ON t2b.id = t1.two_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it in your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT c.day, t.teacher, cl.class, s.subjectname
FROM changes AS c
LEFT JOIN teachers AS t ON c.teacher_id = t.id
JOIN classes AS cl ON c.class_id = cl.id
JOIN subjects AS s ON c.subject_id = s.id
WHERE c.new_teacher_id = t.id
```

Comment: That will turn his `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`